# Use threading to process multiple files

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a file that I need to use to execute the wordcount function(based on `MapReduce`) but using threads, I take the file and split it into multiple small files then I loop the small files to count the number of occurrences of words with a `Reduce()` function, how can I implement threads withe the `run()` function to use them with the Reduce function.

here's my code:

```
public class WordCounter implements Runnable {

private String Nom;
    protected static int Chunks =  1 ;
    public WordCounter (String n) {
        Nom = n;
    }

   public void split () throws IOException
    {

    File source = new File(this.Nom);
    int maxRows = 100;
    int i = 1;

        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(source)){
            String line = null;
            int lineNum = 1;

            File splitFile = new File(this.Nom+i+".txt");

            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(splitFile);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = sc.nextLine();

                if(lineNum > maxRows){
                    Chunks++;
                    myWriter.close();
                    lineNum = 1;
                    i++;
                    splitFile = new File(this.Nom+i+".txt");
                    myWriter = new FileWriter(splitFile);
                }

                myWriter.write(line+"\n");
                lineNum++;
            }

            myWriter.close();

        }

}
public void Reduce() throws IOException 
    {

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

            for (int i = 1; i < Chunks; i++) {

            //create the input stream (recevoir le texte)
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(this.getNom()+i+".txt");
            //go through the text with a scanner
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fin);

            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                //Get the next word
                String nextString = sc.next();

                //Determine if the string exists in words
                if (words.contains(nextString)) {
                    int index = words.indexOf(nextString);

                    count.set(index, count.get(index)+1);

                }
                else {
                    words.add(nextString);
                    count.add(1);
                }
            }
                sc.close();
                fin.close();
            }

            // Creating a File object that represents the disk file. 
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(new File(this.getNom()+"Result.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                myWriter.write(words.get(i)+ " : " +count.get(i) +"\n");    
            }
            myWriter.close();

            //delete the small files
            deleteFiles();
    }
      public void deleteFiles()
    {
        File f= new File("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= Chunks; i++) {
            f = new File(this.getNom()+i+".txt");
            f.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of using [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface and this way you can retrieve your data.

So in order to fix your code you can more or less do something like this:

```
public class WordCounter {
       private static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);  // 5 represents the number of concurrent threads.

       public Map<String, Integer> count(String filename) {
          int chunks = splitFileInChunks(filename);
          List<Future<Report>> reports = new ArrayList<Future<Report>>();

          for (int i=1; i<=chunks; i++) {
             Callable<Report> callable = new ReduceCallable(filename + i + ".txt");
             Future<Report> future = threadPool.submit(callable);
             reports.add(future);
          }

          Map<String, Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
          for (Future<Report> future : reports) {
              Map<String, Integer>  map = future.get().getWords();
              for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                  int oldCnt = finalMap.get(entry.getKey()) != null ? finalMap.get(entry.getKey()) : 0;
                  finalMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() + oldCnt);
              }
          }
          //  return a map with the key being the word and the value the counter for that word
          return finalMap; 
       }

       // this method doesn't need to be run on the separate thread
       private int splitFileInChunks(String filename) throws IOException { .... }
    }

    public class Report {
           Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();
           // ... getter, setter, constructor etc
    }

    public class ReduceCounter implements Callable<Report> { 
        String filename;
        public ReduceCounter(String filename) { this.filename = filename;}

         public Report call() {
            //  store the values in a Map<String, Integer> since it's easier that way
            Map<String, Integer>  myWordsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>;
            // here add the logic from your Reduce method, without the for loop iteration
            // you should add logic to read only the file named with the value from "filename" 

            return new Report(myWordsMap);
         }
    }
```

Please note you can skip the **Report** class and return `Future<Map<String,Integer>>`, but I used Report to make it more easy to follow.

**Update** for Runnable as requested by user

```
public class WordCounter {
         public Map<String, Integer> count(String filename) throws InterruptedException {
           int chunks = splitFileInChunks(filename);
           List<ReduceCounter> counters = new ArrayList<>(); 
           List<Thread> reducerThreads = new ArrayList<>(); 

          for (int i=1; i<=chunks; i++) {
             ReduceCounter  rc = new ReduceCounter(filename + i + ".txt");
             Thread t = new Thread(rc); 
             counters.add(rc);
             reducerThreads.add(t);
             t.start();
          }
          // next wait for the threads to finish processing
          for (Thread t : reducerThreads) {
                t.join();
          }
          // now grab the results from each of them
          for (ReduceCounter cnt : counters ) {
               cnt.getWords();
               // next just merge the results here...
          }
}
```

Reducer class should look like:

```
public class ReduceCounter implements Runnable { 
        String filename;
        Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap();
        public ReduceCounter(String filename) { this.filename = filename;}

         public void run() {
            //  store the values in the "words" map
            // here add the logic from your Reduce method, without the for loop iteration
            // also read, only the file named with the value from "filename" 

         }
        public Map<String, Integer> getWords() {return words;}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, although my professor has insisted that we should use the Runnable interface.

Comment: @AnasCHERIET I've updated the answer with the Runnable solution. More or less that is how you start the threads and get the values from them. Please mark the answer as useful or as accepted if it's good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found a solution as i assign a thread to each small file, then i call the Reduce() function inside the run() function, but i still don't fully have my head around it, here's the code:

```
public void Reduce() throws IOException 
    {

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        Thread TT= new Thread();
            for (int i = 1; i < Chunks; i++) {

            //create the input stream (recevoir le texte)
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(this.getNom()+i+".txt");

            TT=new Thread(this.getNom()+i+".txt");
            TT.start();

            //go through the text with a scanner
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fin);

            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                //Get the next word
                String nextString = sc.next();

                //Determine if the string exists in words
                if (words.contains(nextString)) {
                    int index = words.indexOf(nextString);

                    count.set(index, count.get(index)+1);

                }
                else {
                    words.add(nextString);
                    count.add(1);
                }
            }
                sc.close();
                fin.close();
            }

            // Creating a File object that represents the disk file. 
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(new File(this.getNom()+"Result.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                myWriter.write(words.get(i)+ " : " +count.get(i) +"\n");    
            }
            myWriter.close();

            //Store the result in the new file
            deleteFiles();
    }
public void run() {

        try {
            this.Reduce();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Wordcounter w1 = new Wordcounter("Words.txt");
        Thread T1= new Thread(w1);
        T1.start();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It's still single thread. The threads that you are starting don't do anything. Check my updated answer. In order for another thread to do something you need to pass a runable object to it. Also read this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/runnable-interface-in-java/

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i'm looking for, i will try to implement this in my code